# Action bar with different fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I want to create an app which has Action Bar (v7 appcompat) drop down navigation with 3 different fragments. First fragment is list fragment with tabs, second one is regular fragment and the last one is grid view. I am using fragment transaction to replace fragments in frame layout.

My question is how to make the first one - list fragment with tabs. I suppose I have to use view pager, but for that you need Fragment Activity? Is it possible to add tabs to actual Action Bar?
This is my code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.action_list,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(spinnerAdapter,
                onNavigationListener);
    }

    OnNavigationListener onNavigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new android.support.v4.app.Fragment();
                break;

            case 1:
                fragment = new android.support.v4.app.Fragment();
                break;

            case 2:
                fragment = new android.support.v4.app.Fragment();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Ignore code from switch-case which creates new fragment, they're all same.
Thanks!

Comment: I done it in this project, have a look - [link](https://github.com/daro2189/android_portfolio/blob/master/FunnyApps/src/com/mobile/app/funny/views/MainActivity.java)

Comment: @daro2189 Thank you for your help, but I need first item from drop down navigation to return a lot of tabs with list views, and the other two just regular fragments without tabs.